# Why is the recursive value null?

Tags: f#

I'm F# beginner, I'm having this problem when I'm learning "recursive values".

```ml
type Type = 
    | N of int * Type
    | E

let rec a = N(2, b)
and b = N(3, E)

a |> printfn "%A"
```

I **expect** the output is:

```
N(2, N(3, E))
```

but the actual output is:

```
N (2,null)
```

[image: output]

Comment: What happens if you switch the order of the definitions, and say `let b = N(3, E)` first and then `let a = N(2, b)` afterwards? Note there's no need for `rec` in that case.

Comment: If I change the order in which they are defined, then there is no problem and output N (2, N (3, E)),   But why is it Null?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is actually a bug in the F# compiler, filed here:  https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/issues/847

There has been no indication about when (or if) it will be fixed.

For your particular example, I would recommend simply removing the `rec` modifier: it is not needed, since the values aren't actually recursive. That will make the bug go away.

For more general case, you can create a system of mutually recursive functions for initialization, or simply a nested `let` block. For example, this should work:

```
let a, b =
    let rec a = N(2, b)
    and b = N(3, E)
    a, b
```

Comment: Thanks a million !!!   
Now it can work. 
Although he looks strange  XD

Comment: btw, If I just deleted rec, then it would say : 
"The declaration form 'let ... and ...' for non-recursive bindings is not used in F# code. Consider using a sequence of 'let' bindings " (let)
and
"The value or constructor 'b' is not defined. " (b)

Comment: Well, of course you have to remove `and` as well. `and` is only used with `rec`. I assumed you knew the syntax.

Comment: What am I supposed to do?  my friend

Comment: Remove `rec`, remove `and`

Comment: But it's going to say :"The value or constructor 'b' is not defined."

Comment: my god.  I'm going crazy