# F# recursive bind with "and" gives "null", doesn't work

Tags: f#, recursive-datastructures

This is a brief example from the book, by Tomas Petricek, "Functional programming in the real world", chapter 8.

```
type QueryInfo = 
    {   Title: string
        Check: Client -> bool
        Positive: Decision
        Negative: Decision
    }
and Decision = 
    | Result of string
    | Query of QueryInfo
let rec tree1 = 
    Query({Title=null;Check=(fun cl -> false);Positive=aaa; Negative=aaa})
and aaa = Result("SOME")
```

The problem is - when I use `tree1`, its `.Positive` and `.Negative` are nulls. The same if `aaa` is `Query`, not `Result`. How to fix it?

Comment: Seems here is an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55907218/why-is-the-recursive-value-null?rq=2
The bug in the F# compiler.

Comment: Try making aaa a function, as in `Positive=aaa(); Negative=aaa()})
and aaa() = Result("SOME")`

Comment: No, the compiler doesn't allow it.

Comment: https://replit.com/@robertwharvey1/PrevailingBulkyVisitors#main.fs

Comment: @RobertHarvey an interesting approach. But I can't find the keyword "force". (Yep, I've read about the lazy expressions, and there is .Force() method but I think I don't have it here.) Question 2 - If I have more then 2 components in my "let rec", I should cover with "lazy" each problem type, those show nulls?

Comment: The force function is included in the repl.it code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thank you a lot. I've adapted your sample for my purpose and got this: https://replit.com/@dondublon1/PrevailingBulkyVisitors . There is bit strange notation:  Positive=lazy (force (lazy Result("NO"))) Are two "lazy" ok?